# Prior probability of Normal distribution

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, computational-statistics

I was solving one problem and got to the point where I needed to find the prior probability of the normally distributed variable, with the known mean and variance. I'm a little confused because I've never seen it like this before, but judging by the definition of the prior probability, it will just be the pdf of the normal distribution. Am I right?

Comment: You need to find prior or posterior? What exactly are you asked to do?

Comment: Yes, you (or whoever asked you to do this) define the prior distribution. Without more information and context, we can’t answer your question.